# How do I make a copy of a sent email, to edit and send again

Tags: applescript

I am using Outlook for Mac 2011 version 14.3.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5. I want to take a sent email, make a copy, open, edit and send it again. I used to have an applescript to do this but the link to download it no longer appears to function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it was something like this.

Select you email in the sent iTems and run the script

```
  tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theMessage to item 1 of (get selection) # get the first email message

    set subj to subject of theMessage
    set recip to (email address of to recipient of theMessage)


    set cont to content of theMessage
    set newMail to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:subj, content:cont}

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in recip
        set this_item to item i of recip
        tell newMail to make new recipient at newMail with properties {email address:this_item}
    end repeat

    open newMail
end tell
```

The script creates a new message with ALL previous recipients,subject and content.
Then opens it ready for editing